# C++ Segfault on simple sorting example

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, segmentation-fault

Take a look at this fairly straightforward sorting code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    string Firstname;
    string Sirname;

    Student(const string& firstname, const string& sirname)
        : Firstname(firstname), Sirname(sirname)
    {
    }
};

bool Comparer(const Student& s1, const Student& s2)
{
    return s1.Firstname.compare(s2.Firstname);
}        

int main()
{
    vector<Student> students;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        students.push_back(Student(string("John") + to_string(i), "Smith"));

    sort(students.begin(), students.end() - 1, Comparer);

    for (auto& student: students)
        cout << student.Firstname << endl;
}
```

On g++, std=c++11

```
g++ why.cpp -o why -std=c++11 -g
```

It causes a segfault. On GDB, a backtrace will show the code trying to copy memory from one location to another.

```
#0  __memcmp_sse4_1 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcmp-sse4.S:1011
#1  0x00007ffff7b76278 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0000000000401929 in Comparer (s1=..., s2=...) at why.cpp:21
```

I suspected that one of the strings was invalid so I added a conditional breakpoint like so:

```
break why.cpp:21 if s1.Firstname.empty()
```

And sure enough it hits it. The really weird thing is that if I change the iterator position like so:

```
sort(students.begin(), students.begin(), Comparer);
```

It works. I mean, what the heck? :)

Comment: Look up what `std::string::compare` returns.  It isn't `true` or `false`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Argh... your right. I thought there was something more sinister going on here. Also since the list is sorted to begin with changing the iterator positions will cause the algorithm to finish without a fuss. So much for contrived examples.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, just out of curiosity, do you know why having a bool return type and returning int causes a memcpy?

Comment: `sort(students.begin(), students.begin(), Comparer);` does nothing since you specified an empty range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Comparer` function is supposed to return `true` if the first item in the parameter list is placed before the second parameter when the list is sorted, `false` otherwise

Unfortunately, your `Comparer` function doesn't return `true` or `false`.  Instead it is returning the value of calling the [std::string::compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) function, which returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on the results of the comparison.

To fix your function, do this:

```
bool Comparer(const Student& s1, const Student& s2)
{
    return s1.Firstname.compare(s2.Firstname) < 0;
}
```

That will return `true` if `s1.FirstName < s2.FirstName`, and `false` otherwise.

Or simply do this:

```
bool Comparer(const Student& s1, const Student& s2)
{
    return s1.Firstname < s2.Firstname;
}
```